# Cannot press a button 2nd time to active the rotate after pressing the other buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with my code: I cannot press a button a second time to active the rotate after I press the other buttons.

You'll see my problem here http://jsfiddle.net/HCP46/8/:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#continue1").click(function(){
$(".rotate").toggleClass("rotate1");
});
$("#continue2").click(function(){
$(".rotate").toggleClass("rotate2");
});
$("#continue3").click(function(){
$(".rotate").toggleClass("rotate3");
});
$("#continue4").click(function(){
$(".rotate").toggleClass("rotate4");
});
$("#continue5").click(function(){
$(".rotate").toggleClass("rotate5");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Suppose that I click the "Continue1", I see what happens the first time I click.  If I click the same button again, what should I expect to see, additional rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all of the other `rotate` classes as they will take precedence in the CSS.

You can also make this a lot simpler with a single binding that derives the rotate class name from the element.

```
$("button").on('click', function () {
    $(".rotate").removeClass().addClass("rotate rotate" + $(this).text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HCP46/9/